# Java Square Matrix column major iterator

Tags: java, matrix, iterator

I am quite confused on putting together a column major iterator for a square matrix based on a T[][] array...

we have a get method that is get(row, column) for matrix[i][j] where i is row and j is column...

```
private class SquareMatrixIterator implements Iterator<T> {

    //Do not add any instance variables
    private int row;
    private int column;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(row >= (matrix.length - 1) && column >= (matrix[0].length - 1)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (hasNext()) {
            if (row < matrix.length - 1) {
                row++;
            } else {
                row = 0;
                column++;
            }

            return get(row, column);

        } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

    }
}
```

is the code I had thought of so far but is definitely not working... i am not sure if i am doing it wrong and supposed to use while loop... or if its just the hasNext that is wrong ... but if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us what is not working? Is it not compiling or is it returning incorrect results?

Comment: My teacher gave us a JUnit file to run to make sure it was running correctly and I am getting lots of errors so yeah incorrect results I assume.

Comment: Oh I hadn't realised it was homework. I'll edit my answer to provide some hints rather than the code.

Comment: Can you post some info on the failing tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have several errors

1. When `column == matrix[0].length - 1` there is still 1 element left to process.
2. Similar issue with row equality.
3. You are assuming all rows are the same length. I realise it's a matrix but it would be safer if you compared `column` to `matrix[row].length`
4. You don't need `if(...) then return false else return true`. Just return the boolean expression (e.g. return `row < matrix.length && column < matrix[row].length`
5. You are incrementing row and column before processing the cell so you will never process cell [0][0] - you should increment after getting the value to return

So I am suggesting something like:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return row < matrix.length && col < matrix[row].length;
}

public T next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
        throw ...
    } else if (col < matrix[row].length) {
        return matrix[row][col++];
    } else {
        return matrix[row++][col = 0];
    }
}
```

Comment: lets say its a 3x3 matrix... the index's for column and row are 0 , 1 , and 2... when its at the last item in the matrix it will be at [2][2], so thats why i was checking if the column was equal to the length - 1 because isnt the length 3 on a 3x3?

Comment: Your code reads that there are no more elements when col == 2 and row == 2. That's not true: there's still [2][2] to process. There are no more elements when col == 3

Comment: Note my issue 5 - you should increment after processing not before

Comment: ah i see thanks so much I will try and work on it with that in mind and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Ok I'll post code after all - in case the errors I have listed aren't clear.

Comment: cool yeah you helped alot I got it working from your advice actually but I appreciate the code anyway!